# How to atomically increment a value with addx?

Tags: inline-assembly

Doing a research on stackoveflow I have found this code:

```
 asm(
       "lock\n\t"
       "xadd %1, %0":
       "+m"( mem), "=r"(r):
       "1"( val ):
       "memory", "cc");
```

The `lock` instruction is there to ensure atomicity in case of concurrent access, now the `xadd` adds the content of the two regiters and put the result in the first one.

However I don't understand the rest of the code : If `mem = r` then increment the memory content with `(val)` in this case 1. Does r refer to the expected value ? Can any of these values be returned using a simple return, `return mem` for example. Is the `xadd` operation intel specific ?

Comment: "The rest" of that statement isn't assembler code.  Those are the list of output, input and clobbers.  See docs for extended asm [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: Now that I have read the tutorial, the `mem` is the address of the value to be incremented, by `val` which can be declared before as `int val = 1`.